# castle windsor doesn't inject dependency into properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, castle-windsor

I have asp.net mvc application. I have created a custom membership provider
that is bound in web.config like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyProject.Infrastructure.Security.MyMembershipProvider" /> 
    </providers>
</membership>
```

I use Castle Windsor for IoC. Usually I use the constructor injection something like:

```
SomeController(ISomething something)
{
  something.do();
  ...
}
```

I can not use this for the custom membership class because I get an error from web.config that I don't have a parameterless constructor. But if I used a parameterless constructor the object wouldn't be initialized.

So I used property injection like so:

```
<castle>
    <components>
        <component id="usersRepos" service="MyProject.Core.Repositories.IUserRepository, MyProject.Core" type="MyProject.Data.RepositoryImplementations, MyProject.Data"></component>
    </components>
</castle>
```

...

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{ 
    public IUserRepository UserRepository{get; set;}

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {            
        if (UserRepository.UserExists(username, password))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And I get object reference not found exception because the object (UserRepository) has not been initialized.

Comment: Is your class correctly registered? if you try to resolve IUserRepository will it succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Membership providers can't be managed by Windsor (or at least it seems that nobody bothered to find out how to do it) so they will never get anything injected. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003587/how-to-integrate-ioc-membership-provider-with-asp-net-mvc/1004806#1004806) for a workaround.

UPDATE: [I wrote about a better, seamless, workaround](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html)